# Actual build date in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros, predefined-macro

I need to get build date of a module. I use `__DATE__` macro. But it looks like if the file which contains this macro is not changed then it is not compiled and build date is left old and incorrect. How to make sure that build date updates? Maybe there is another way to get build date of the module?

Comment: There is no such thing as "module". A C++ program consists of translation units. `__DATE__` expands to the date of translation of a particular translation unit,

Comment: You need to recompile the translation unit that contains `__DATE__` every time you build.

Comment: You should recompile your project from scratch. You may also consider switching away from the build system that tries to figure out whether file has been modified prior to building.

Comment: It's better to use a global variable here. BTW why you want to update the build date if a module wasn't actually rebuilt?

Comment: Putting any kind of timestamp inside will of course make it produce a different object file every time you compile (even though the real code has not changed) which will in turn make it hard to have some sort of build avoidance based on checksums of the derived objects like many build systems depend on.

Answer (score 2):

Everything you write is correct and works as it should:

When you use a build system, a file is only compiled when it has been changed, i.e. it is newer than the corresponding object file. So, you will always get the date when this particular file was compiled.

To get a new build date every time that any file of an application/library has changed, you have to make sure that the file that stores the build date is built every time too.
Normally a build system supports something like that, an option like "build always". Another (not recommended) way would be to delete the object file every time before you compile. Or (even worse), always make a clean build, i.e. delete everything and build everything every time.

Comment: "_changed, i.e. it is newer_" - Yes, that's the `gmake` (and some others) take on it, but it's not universal. _Newer_ is a rather crude way of detecting change i.m.o. Some systems also detect a negative timestamp change as a change and some don't even care about timestamps and use checksums instead, which makes it possible to "touch" every source file without rebuilding anything. Forcefully rebuilding a target for which no dependencies have been changed feels like something one does when not trusting the stated dependencies or tools involved.